# Mapping two values to a single property with Orika

Tags: java, orika

Suppose I have a source object, containing two properties, a and b like this:

```
public class Source {
    String a, b;
}
```

and a target object with one property c:

```
public class Target {
    String c;
}
```

I'd like to define a mapping that will:

1. map property a to c if a is not null
2. map property b to c if b is not null

I thought it would be possible with a mapper with mapNulls set to false:

```
factory.registerClassMap(factory.classMap(Source.class, Target.class).field("a", "c").field("b", "c").mapNulls(false));
```

However, when I set property a to a non-null value and leave property b to null, the mapping results in a target object with c set to null.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of mapNulls?

Comment: Well, I never tried to use `mapNulls`. At these custom rules I implement a `ConfigurableMapper`, some extra work but seems reasonable.
Maybe the reason is because `mapNulls` is field level, try setting `mapNulls` for both fields.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. All seems a bit dodgy though, .field() returns the ClassMapBuilder for method-chaining, apparently .setNulls() only affects the last field added...

Comment: mapNulls exists on MapperFactory/ClassMap/FieldMap levels ... the most specific level can override the more generic one.

Comment: You can also use the recent way (more simple) to register a class-map: factory.classMap(Source.class, Target.class).field("a", "c").field("b", "c").mapNulls(false).register();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `mapNulls` set the property at the last field.
Try setting at both fields.
You can implement a `ConfigurableMapper` too.